# Number.IsInteger() in if else statement not working

Tags: javascript, html, web

```js
function bereken() {
  input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  input1Valid = Number.isInteger(document.getElementById('input1'));
  input2Valid = Number.isInteger(document.getElementById('input2'));

  if (Number.isInteger(input1) && Number.isInteger(input2)) {
     alert('De getallen zijn allebei hele getallen')
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='code.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>GGD calculator</h1>
      <p>Reken de Grote Gemene Deler uit van <input type='number' id='input1'> en <input type='number' id='input2'>.</p>
      <br>
      <input type='button' value='Bereken!' onClick='bereken()'>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was practising JavaScript and I came across this issue, can anybody help me?

I want it to alert my message when both numbers entered are integers, why is this not working?

Comment: Remember that the "T" in HTML stands for "Text". There is only one data type in HTML - string. Any value you pull from HTML will always be a string.

Comment: You need to convert the string first into a Number. Use `parseInt(value, 10)` to convert it to a Number. Then, you can check the return value if it is a non-float integer.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 You can also just place `+` directly in front of the string to convert it to a number.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The value of the #num element is returned as a string as you can see in the console. Just revert it to a number using `+` sign.

```js
function bereken() {
  input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  
  if (Number.isInteger(+input1) && Number.isInteger(+input2)) {
     alert('De getallen zijn allebei hele getallen')
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='code.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>GGD calculator</h1>
      <p>Reken de Grote Gemene Deler uit van <input type='number' id='input1'> en <input type='number' id='input2'>.</p>
      <br>
      <input type='button' value='Bereken!' onClick='bereken()'>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```